# Operator Overloading Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

The issue I am having is how to get the correct number columns to go through for the inner most loop of K.
An example is a 2x3 matrix and a 3x2 matrix being multiplied.
The result should be a 2x2 matrix, but currently I dont know how to send the value of 2 to the operator overloaded function.
It should be
int k = 0; k < columns of first matrix;k++

```
  Matrix::Matrix(int row, int col)
   {
    rows = row;
    cols = col;
    cx = (float**)malloc(rows * sizeof(float*));  //initialize pointer to pointer matrix
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      *(cx + i) = (float*)malloc(cols * sizeof(float));
    }



Matrix Matrix::operator * (Matrix dx)
 {
   Matrix mult(rows, cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
     { 
       for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            mult.cx[i][j] = 0;
           for (int k = 0; k < ?;k++) //?????????????
            {
                 mult.cx[i][j] += cx[i][k] * dx.cx[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
      mult.print();
      return mult;


 //calling
  Matrix mult(rowA, colB);
           mult = mat1 * mat2;
}
```

Comment: Please don't add multiple language tags to a question. Only use the tag for the language you're using.

Comment: Sorry to be a bore but it will take an age to get a matrix class working. Use BLAS, which is part of the Boost distribution.

Comment: `cx = (float**)malloc(rows * sizeof(float*));` is Undefined Behaviour in C++ Why are you not using `std::vector` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear algebra rules say the result should have dimensions rows x dx.cols

```
    Matrix Matrix::operator * (Matrix dx)
    {
     Matrix mult(rows, dx.cols);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
     { 
       for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            mult.cx[i][j] = 0;
           for (int k = 0; k < cols;k++) //?????????????
            {
                 mult.cx[i][j] += cx[i][k] * dx.cx[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
      mult.print();
      return mult;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few random hints:

- Your code is basically C; it doesn’t use (e.g.) important memory-safety features from C++. (Operator overloading is the only C++-like feature in use.) I suggest that you take advantage of C++ a bit more.
- Strictly avoid `malloc()` in C++. Use `std::make_unique(...)` or, if there is no other way, a raw `new` operator. (BTW, there is *always* another way.) In the latter case, make sure there is a destructor with a `delete` or `delete[]`. The use of `malloc()` in your snippet smells like a memory leak.
- What *can* be `const` *should* be `const`. Initialize as many class members as possible in the constructor’s initializer list and make them `const` if appropriate. (For example, `Matrix` dimensions don’t change and should be `const`.)
- When writing a container-like class (which a `Matrix` may be, in a sense), don’t restrict it to a single data type; your future self will thank you. (What if you need a `double` instead of a `float`? Is it going to be a one-liner edit or an all-nighter spent searching where a forgotten `float` eats away your precision?)

Here’s a quick and dirty runnable example showing matrix multiplication:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

namespace matrix {
using std::size_t;

template<typename Element>
class Matrix {
  class Accessor {
   public:
    Accessor(const Matrix& mat, size_t m) : data_(&mat.data_[m * mat.n_]) {}
    Element& operator [](size_t n) { return data_[n]; }
    const Element& operator [](size_t n) const { return data_[n]; }

   private:
    Element *const data_;
  };

 public:
  Matrix(size_t m, size_t n) : m_(m), n_(n),
                               data_(std::make_unique<Element[]>(m * n)) {}
  Matrix(Matrix &&rv) : m_(rv.m_), n_(rv.n_), data_(std::move(rv.data_)) {}

  Matrix operator *(const Matrix& right) {
    Matrix result(m_, right.n_);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_; ++i)
      for (size_t j = 0; j < right.n_; ++j) {
        result[i][j] = Element{};
        for (size_t k = 0; k < n_; ++k) result[i][j] +=
            (*this)[i][k] * right[k][j];
      }
    return result;
  }

  Accessor operator [](size_t m) { return Accessor(*this, m); }
  const Accessor operator [](size_t m) const { return Accessor(*this, m); }
  size_t m() const { return m_; }
  size_t n() const { return n_; }

 private:
    const size_t m_;
    const size_t n_;
    std::unique_ptr<Element[]> data_;
};

template<typename Element>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &out, const Matrix<Element> &mat) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < mat.m(); ++i) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < mat.n(); ++j) out << std::setw(4) << mat[i][j];
    out << std::endl;
  }
  return out;
}
}  // namespace matrix

int main() {
  matrix::Matrix<int> m22{2, 2};
  m22[0][0] = 0;  // TODO: std::initializer_list
  m22[0][1] = 1;
  m22[1][0] = 2;
  m22[1][1] = 3;

  matrix::Matrix<int> m23{2, 3};
  m23[0][0] = 0;  // TODO: std::initializer_list
  m23[0][1] = 1;
  m23[0][2] = 2;
  m23[1][0] = 3;
  m23[1][1] = 4;
  m23[1][2] = 5;

  matrix::Matrix<int> m32{3, 2};
  m32[0][0] = 5;  // TODO: std::initializer_list
  m32[0][1] = 4;
  m32[1][0] = 3;
  m32[1][1] = 2;
  m32[2][0] = 1;
  m32[2][1] = 0;

  std::cout << "Original:\n\n";
  std::cout << m22 << std::endl << m23 << std::endl << m32 << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Multiplied:\n\n";
  std::cout << m22 * m22 << std::endl
            << m22 * m23 << std::endl
            << m32 * m22 << std::endl
            << m23 * m32 << std::endl
            << m32 * m23 << std::endl;
}
```

Possible improvements and other recommendations:

- Add consistency checks. `throw`, for example, a `std::invalid_argument` when dimensions don’t match on multiplication, i.e. when `m_ != right.n_`, and a `std::range_error` when the `operator []` gets an out-of-bounds argument. (The checks may be optional, activated (e.g.) for debugging using an `if constexpr`.)
- Use a `std::initializer_list` or the like for initialization, so that you can have (e.g.) a `const Matrix` initialized in-line.
- **Always** check your code using `valgrind`. (Tip: Buliding with `-g` lets `valgrind` print also the line numbers where something wrong happened (or where a relevant preceding (de)allocation had happened).)
- The code could me made shorter and more elegant (not necessarily more efficient; compiler optimizations are magic nowadays) by *not* using `operator []` everywhere and having some fun with pointer arithmetics instead.
- Make the type system better, so that (e.g.) `Matrix` instances with different types can play well with each other. Perhaps a `Matrix<int>` multiplied by a `Matrix<double>` could yield a `Matrix<double>` etc. One could also support multiplication between a scalar value and a `Matrix`. Or between a `Matrix` and a `std::array`, `std::vector` etc.