# The function of matrix multiplication c++

Tags: c++, class, matrix, overloading

I have to overload the operator *= of the matrix class. The function always gives me as result 0, and she doesn't create the matrix with right columns.
Under here I'll leave the function code. Thank you.

```
void Matrice::operator*=(Matrice m) {
if (cols == m.rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            for (int r = 0; r < cols; r++)
                mat[i][r] *= m.mat[r][j];   //here probably there is the error
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gives me as result 0,"? Are you saying that the matrix gets filled filled 0s?

Comment: We have no idea what `Matrice` really is, how it is populated, where it is initialized, or how it is used.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: I don't know how this compiles. What is mat and what are you doing with it?

Comment: You should pass `Matrice` by reference, or `const` reference if you are not changing the parameter.  Without pass by reference, the compiler will make a copy of the `Matrice` and then pass to the function; usually the copy is placed on the stack (that has smaller capacity).  Passing by reference allows the compiler to access the Caller's `Matrice` directly.

Comment: If you could provide full content of you `Matrice` class then I could show you how to properly fix it by using tests.

Comment: [The algorithm is on StackOverflow a number of times.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69608341/8584929) You need `+=` to implement `*=`: the synopsis of the inner cycle is `output[i][j] += left_input[i][r] * right_input[r][j];`. But your loop bounds are wrong; fix them first. Also, the method’s signature is a bad idea. Start from `Matrix& Matrix::operator *=(const Matrix& m);` and maybe add optimized versions later (`const`-qualified, `&&`-qualified, with a `&&` argument etc.). The very existence of `*=` may be a design flaw: Matrix dimensions cannot be `const` and must change dynamically.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek I've already overloaded the operator* and here I've used This code:  output[i][j] += left_input[i][r] * right_input[r][j]; 
My question is for the abbreviate form of the moltiplication ( *= ).